# How to calculate the resultant vector

Tags: geometry, vectors

The vector $A=5i+6j$ is rotated through an $\angle 45$ about the $Z$ axis in the anticlockwise direction. What is the resultant vector?

My attempt:
I tried to calculate the resultant vector by using the equation, 
$R=\sqrt{A^2+B^2+2ABCos\theta} $

since it is rotated in anticlockwise direction its direction changes.
Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: What tools do you have available to you?  This should be trivial using [matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

Comment: This is a question for entrance exam in our university. Will you please help me with a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

**First approach**

You can solve it by considering the rotation matrix, where $(x',y')$ are the new coordinates after the rotation:
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
x'\\
y'
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) & -\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\\
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
5\\
6
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

**Second approach**

Since $A = 5i + 6j = (5,6)$, you can multiply it by $\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}{4}\right)$.

Comment: It was really helpful

Answer (score 2):

1) $\vec {i} \rightarrow (1/√2)(\vec {i} +\vec {j})$;

2) $\vec {j} \rightarrow (1/√2)(\vec {-i}+\vec {j})$;

3) $5 \vec {i} +6 \vec {j} \rightarrow $

$(1/√2)(-1)\vec {i} +(1/√2)(11)\vec {j}$.